# How can I make miniconda to see virtual environments created earlier?

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I have some virtual environment called `pyenv` that was created with Miniconda. After I reinstalled Windows and installed Miniconda again I'd like Miniconda see old virtual environment.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the answer is very simple:

```
activate path/to/your/virtual/environment/folder
```